# Getting ConcurrentException when working with list

Tags: java

I am working with below code :

```
List<String> layerDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
if (layerDataList.isEmpty()) {
  layerDataList.add(layerData);
}

Iterator<String> lir = layerDataList.iterator(); // Iterator created

while (lir.hasNext()) {
  String layerD = lir.next();
  if (layerD != layerData) {
    layerDataList.add(layerData);
  }
}
```

I got exception : `java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)`

What is the issue?

Comment: Also, let's just throw in [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for good measure.

Comment: you have to use methods on `Iterator` and `ListIterator` to add and remove elements from list, don't do it directly on `List` itself. [See question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing)

Comment: read about Fail-Safe and Fail-Fast in collection. It's great if you will google it.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Do you assume that the correct answer will change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't traverse through the list using `Iterator` and modify the list with List-level `add/remove` methods at the same time.

To add an element in such situations you can use `ListIterator` and its method [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add-E-).

Comment: Actually he *can* **remove**

Comment: @Andremoniy but only with the `Iterator`'s remove method, not the `List`'s.

Comment: @AndyTurner Obviously. This wasn't clarified in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you modify a `Collection`, you invalidate all the `Iterator`s that depend on it. Instead, you could use the iterator itself (assuming you define it as a `ListIterator`, or something down those lines) to modify the collection:

```
ListIterator<String> lir = layerDataList.iterator();
while (lir.hasNext()) {
  String layerD = lir.next();
  if (layerD != layerData) {
    lir.add(layerData); // Here!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) says:

> The iterators returned by this ArrayList's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

To add while iterating to a list you can try like this:

```
ListIterator<String> lir = layerDataList.iterator();
while (lir.hasNext()) {
  String layerD = lir.next();
  if (layerD != layerData) {
    lir.add(layerData); 
  }
}
```